# Does any one use OSGi's OBR?

Tags: java, osgi, obr

Is anyone using the OSGi Bundle Repository and what for?

Answer (score 9):

I tried it in apache felix, i think it's great. You can point your osgi container to a number of obrs and when you install a bundle, the container will automatically install all required dependencies.

It's like *apt-get install* for application servers.

Answer (score 7):

I am using it!

When you develop an osgi bundle and the target platform doesn't include the libraries (jar/bundle) your bundle relies on, it needs to added to the target platform. you could either repackage your jar to make it an osgi bundle or just download the bundle from the OBR.

Eclipse also provides an OBR call [Orbit](http://www.eclipse.org/orbit/), and springsource one is called [Enterprise Bundle Repository](http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/).